# How is this code with reduce function evaluating in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, reduce

Following is the Clojure code:

```
(reduce (fn [r x] (if (nil? x) r (conj r x)))  
        []  
        [:mouse nil :duck nil :lory nil])
```

In REPL, it evaluates to `[:mouse :duck :lory]`.

My question is, how is the code evaluating?

According to me, `r` is `[]` and `x` is `[:mouse nil :duck nil :lory nil]`. `nil? x` is false as so it evaluates to `(conj r x)`. But x is a vector, not an element so how it will add an element to the empty vector r in `conj`? I don't know but I am wrong somewhere in my approach. The output is the animals' name vector without nil values.
Can anyone please explain me the execution of code. Thanks.

Comment: Quick comment, when formatting standard practice is to align function arguments horizontally (which I've done for you). Please do try it makes the code much easier to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem appears to be understanding how `reduce` works. I'd like to refer you to the source code, but it simply maps onto a Java implementation, so I have to fake it.

The kind of `reduce` you are doing - supplying the initial value - might have been coded as follows:

```
(defn reduce [f init coll]
  (loop [acc init, tail coll]
    (if (seq tail)
      (recur (f acc (first tail)) (rest tail))
      acc)))
```

As you can see, it works through the sequence `coll`, applying the function `f` to `acc` and the first value in the sequence, to generate a new `acc`. When there is no more sequence, it returns `acc`.

How does this apply to your example? The reducing function ...

```
(fn [r x] (if (nil? x) r (conj r x)))
```

... ignores `nil` `x`s but `conj`s anything else onto the end of the accumulating vector `r`. Your code is more or less equivalent to ...

```
(remove nil? [:mouse nil :duck nil :lory nil])
=> (:mouse :duck :lory)
```

... except you get a lazy sequence instead of a vector.

Comment: As for the first, ```r``` will be ```[]``` and ```x``` will be ```:mouse```. As x is not nil, it will ```conj``` ```x``` to the end of ```r```. Then ```r``` will be ```(:mouse)``` and ```x``` will be ```nil``` for the second element. Here, ```(nil? x)``` will be evaluated ```true``` and it will return ```r```. Should it give ```(:mouse)``` as it exited with ```r``` when the element was nil. But it gives ```(:mouse :duck :lory)```. Where am I wrong?

Comment: `reduce` continues reducing over the input vector. It didn't exit, it just returned `[:mouse]` and the next reduction step starts with `[:mouse]` and `:duck`.

Comment: @leydovordu I've added an explanation of how `reduce` works. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Courtesy of [FredOverflow's Clojure Transducers from the ground up](https://youtu.be/TaazvSJvBaw?t=275) you can wrap the reducing `fn` in this `logging` function to print the different arguments (r and x) to every step:

```clj
(defn logging [f]
  (fn [& args]
    (prn args)
    (apply f args)))

(reduce (logging (fn [r x] (if (nil? x) r (conj r x))))
        []  
        [:mouse nil :duck nil :lory nil])
```

> user=> ([] :mouse) 
>              ([:mouse] nil)
>              ([:mouse] :duck)
>              ([:mouse :duck] nil)
>              ([:mouse :duck] :lory)
>              ([:mouse :duck :lory] nil)

So only the keywords are added (not nils), starting with `[]`. At the end `[:mouse :duck :lory]` is returned.